# CarouselView dynamic height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have now spent like forever trying to figure out what I thought would be the easiest and most obvious functionality of the carouselView: Height according to content.

No matter what I do, the height of the CarouselView is the screen height. I do not want that as my content is dynamic text which can have different sizes. The page consists of a static top, the contentView and a static bottom of data.

I know that it might actually be the way it works (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8640) which to me makes the carouselView totally useless unless using static images of a static height.

However I am still hoping, that I am wrong. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**
The issue might be, that I want the CarouselView inside a ScrollView, as I want it to be a part of the page. Inside a scrollView the CarouselView will get the height of the page and not the content. Can that be solved?

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Hello!" />
    <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Challenge.ChallengeParts}" Position="{Binding PageCarouselPosition}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="red">
                    <Label Text="Hello! inside CarouselView" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <Label Text="Hello!" />
</StackLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
This will be some of the desired content of the CV:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="green">
  <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Label Text="Vis regler fra video" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
      <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=BindingContext.ShowRules,Converter={StaticResource CaretConverter}}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
  </Grid>

  <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=BindingContext.ShowRules}">
      <Grid Margin="20, 0, 0, 0">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <!--Antal spillere-->
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
              <Label Text="&#xf183;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
              <Label Text="&#xf182;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout Spacing="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
              <Label Text="Antal spillere:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Micro" />
              <Label Text="{Binding NumPlayers}" FontSize="Micro" />
          </StackLayout>
          <!--Nødvendigt udstyr-->
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
              <Label Text="&#xf45d;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout Spacing="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
              <Label Text="Nødvendigt udstyr:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Micro" />
              <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding NeededAccesories}" Spacing="0">
                  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="Micro" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
              </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
          <!--Regler-->
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
              <Label Text="&#xf46d;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="30" />
          </StackLayout>
          <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
              <Label Text="Regler:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Micro" />
              <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Rules}" Spacing="0">
                  <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="Micro" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
              </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
            <Frame
              BorderColor="Transparent"
              HasShadow="false" 
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              Padding="0"
              CornerRadius="0"
              IsVisible="{Binding HasTopImages}">
              <grial:Repeater
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{ Binding Source={x:Reference thisPage}, Path=BindingContext.Gallery }"
                  Orientation="Horizontal"
                  HeightRequest="350"
                  Spacing="15"
                  ItemSize="350"
                  ScrollPadding="20,0"
                  ScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                  >
                  <grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <local:FullHeaderArticleGalleryItemTemplate />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </grial:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
              </grial:Repeater>
          </Frame>
      </Grid>
  </StackLayout>
```

**UPDATE 3:**
I have tried to calculate the heights as suggested. It works... almost. I can resize to correct sizes with this piece of code:

```
        private void UpdateCarouselViewHeight()
        {
            var cvVisibleViews = cv.VisibleViews;
            if(cvVisibleViews.Count > 0)
            {
                //cv.HeightRequest = 1;
                var rulesStack = cvVisibleViews[0].FindByName<StackLayout>("showRulesStack");
                var toggleShowRules = cvVisibleViews[0].FindByName<StackLayout>("toggleShowRules");
                var showRulesText = cvVisibleViews[0].FindByName<Label>("showRulesText");

                double height = 0;
                height = height + toggleShowRules.Height;
                height = height + showRulesText.Height;
                if (rulesStack.IsVisible && rulesStack.Height > -1)
                {
                    height = height + rulesStack.Height;
                }
                cvVisibleViews[0].HeightRequest = height;
                cv.HeightRequest = height;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: this does not really demonstrate the problem you are having.  You don't have any height values or layout constraints set on your elements, so they will typically expand to fill their containers.  If you want your CV height to vary according to content, you most likely need to manually calculate the height in code and assign it.